# adding interactive label to a window based iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to add a variable label to a simple window base iPhone application.
I am using XCode 3.2.6.
The app is an exaple I downloaded from the web and is just as simple as this:

- a label where the user can type some text
- a submit button

When the user clicks on submit, the text in the label is recorded in a mysql database with a simple query (the db is on my local machine and handled with a php script). 
The query works, I just would like to add the label to write the result of the query.
So I added this code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, 20.0f)];
[label setText:@"write some text"];
```

But it doesn't work. 
Do I need to connect the label to some object in Interface Builder?
Thanks so much

Comment: Where exactly do you add the label to the window ? Since you created the label yourself you need to add it by yourself (no connectors) to the window

Answer (score 1):

i think you forget to add label to your view like this :

```
[self.view addSubView: label];
```

this will insert your label on your current view

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` sounds a better solution... With that, you can edit the message and set programmatically the text. 
Doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

Comment: -1 this should be comment than an answer as you do not exactly solve the OP problem or at least show whats wrong and how can it be fixed

Comment: Since, I think that is a problem of conception and knowledge of the different elements given by the iOS SDK (customize `UILabel` to work as a `UITextField` sounds weird), this could be the correct answer, no? I edited the post to be more consistant.

Comment: I added it just after the code that handles the click on the button and the database interaction.
In the console I get the response from the db, but I would like to see the response in the label.
Here is the code

 NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/phpFile.php?name=%@", txtName.text];
 NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
 NSString *strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]  autorelease];
 NSLog(@"%@", strResult);

Comment: @Larme, my point was that your answer is way to "thin" with no explanation. Throwing a certain term in the air is not an answer. The idea is to lead the OP to a solution and not showing him a page of UITextField without even explaining why this would work for him nor how.

Answer (score 0):

You should better make the UILabel *label as the property of the AppDelegate.

And then in the AppDelegate.m , you can init the UILabel

```
_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, 20.0f)];
```

At the end of your code of Launch , you should add the `_label` to the window bring the `_label` to front

```
[self.window addSubView:_label]
```

and in AppDelegate you should public a method to set the text.

```
- (void)showText:(NSString *)text
{
    [_label setText:text];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:_label];
}
```

And In your view or viewControll(should improt your AppDelegate.h) , when you click the submit button

```
- (void)clickSubmitButton:(UIButton)button
{
        // TODO : get your text string
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate showText:YOURTEXT];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, why do I get "label: undeclared" ?

Comment: in the AppDelegate.h add the label property like this : @property (nonatomic) UILabel *label;

Comment: Yes I already did that, but label is still undeclared!Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I missed the @synthesize label !